# code after await axios post call is not running, no error in catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise, axios

I cannot figure out why the code after this line does not run:

```
const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/comment', {
                content,
            });
```

The comment gets created on the backend and saved to the database. The server side code works, I tested it in Postman and I get the correct response. I am not getting an error in the catch on the frontend. Help please.

CLIENT

CreateComment.js

```
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/comment', {
                content,
            });
            //after this line does not run
            //comment is successfully saved to database
            console.log(res.body);
            props.history.push(`/comment/${res.body.id}`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
```

SERVER

comment.js (controller)

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
        try {

            const newComment = await Comment.create({
                content: req.body.content,
            });

            return res.send(newComment);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            return res.status(400).send(e);
        }
}
```

EDIT:

response body in Postman:

```
{"id":34,"content":"happy tuesday","tone":"joy","updatedAt":"2021-04-01T16:06:07.333Z","createdAt":"2021-04-01T16:06:07.333Z"}
```

CreateComment.js (full component)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function CreateComment(props) {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/comment', 
            {
                content,
            });
            debugger;
            console.log(res);
            return props.history.push(`/comment/${res.data.id}`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='form'>
            <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit()}>
                <div className='form-input'>
                    {/* Controlled Input */}
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        name='content'
                        onChange={e => setContent(e.target.value)}
                        value={content}
                        className='inputForm'
                    />
                </div>
                <input type='submit' value='Curate' className='button' />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(CreateComment);
```

Comment: Can you show the console.log output of `res` ? or the Postman output or screenshot?

Comment: In your server file try returning `return res.status(201).send(newComment);`

Comment: @BikkiMahato i added the postman response body. The `console.log(res.body)` does not run, nor does the `history.push()`
i changed to this: `return res.status(201).send(newComment);` but Im still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you try out by adding appropriate headers in you axios call, sometimes are issues related to the headers.

Comment: The comment is created and saved to the DB when I run the frontend code.

Comment: i added the headers but still the same issue.

Comment: If you add a `debugger;` after the offending line, does it trigger? If so, what does `res` look like?

Comment: @samuei tried that. debugger does not run after the line in question.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I had not checked that yet, thank you. The request is not showing up in the network panel at all. This is strange since I can see on the backend that the call is made and a comment is created in the database.

Comment: You should use `res.data` instead of `res.body` as it doesn't exist on an axios [Response object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema). Still doesn't explain why your `catch` doesn't actually _catch_ any error though...

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova okay. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and still the same issue. code after the call does not run, i have a debugger there that is not triggering. It is also not showing up in the network pannel.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I tried it with just `const res = await axios.post('reqbin.com/echo/post/json');` I am still having the same errors. what do you mean by bwt?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Thank you for taking so much time to try and help me. Unfortunately, I am still having the same error with that change. Something I noticed was its adding `?content=this+is+a+comment` to the url in my browser. the content is just a string.

Comment: If the debugger isn't being hit, I suspect your browser's not getting back a response that it recognizes as complete, so it's still `await`ing res.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I added the full component. sorry for the late response.

Comment: @samuei when i have a debugger before, the code stops running after that line. it does not seem like its still `await`ing.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova yes that worked. thank you so much you are the best!

Comment: Solutions go in the answer space, not in the question. I rolled back your edit

Comment: @gibby I will post it as an answer then and remove my comments so it is all a bit more tidy :)

Answer (score 2):

The `axios` request is made on submit event of a form here. The default behavior on submit is to submit the form and navigate to a new URL, this results in the browser aborting the request as it assumes the request is no longer needed. Adding `e.preventDefault();` to the event handler will fix this, here is a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-playground-forked-s9op7?file=/index.js